# What happens to a particle and antiparticle that collide?

Tags: particle-physics, energy-conservation, mass-energy, antimatter

Matter can never be destroyed, so what happens to those particles? Do they just disappear? Where does the mass go?

Comment: *"Matter can never be destroyed"* is only an approximate rule appropriate to chemistry and intro physics classes, but not actually respected by the universe. The energy remains.

Comment: @dmckee So why would that concept be taught if it isn't true?

Comment: Because it is approximately true to a degree that makes it useful. Because beginners need to use it at times and don't need to be bothered with the rather more subtle truth until they have mastered the basics. Because it was believed to be true until the early 20th century.

Comment: Pies : sadly a lot of things are taught that aren't true. And there is _no_ good reason for teaching _lies to Pies_. Note that Newton knew that matter could be converted into light in something as simple as a fire. Not much, but some. See [Opticks query 30](http://inters.org/newton-opticks-queries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following diagram and explanation from Cornell University's page [A Brief Introduction to Particle Physics](http://www.lns.cornell.edu/~nbm/NBM_INTRO_TO_HEP1.htm#_Toc53191498) may be of help:

[image]

(Note, as correctly mentioned by @HDE in the comments, the term 'mini Big Bang' is a bit misleading, but the main point remains as @Jon Custer mentioned in the comments:

> The mass gets converted into energy. And energy can be converted into mass

A bit more detail from the Cornell site:

> In head-on collisions between high-energy particles and their antiparticles, pure energy is created in "little bangs" when the particles and their antiparticles annihilate each other and disappear. This energy is then free to reappear as pairs of fundamental particles, e.g., a quark-antiquark pair, or an electron-positron pair, etc.

Comment: I know that this is the fault of the image, not you, but "mini Big Bang" is a little misleading.

Comment: Good point @HDE226868 I will make a little notation of that in the answer

Answer (score 1):

"Matter can never be destroyed, so what happens to those particles? Do they just disappear? Where does the mass go?"

It's not true that "matter can never be destroyed". According to classical understanding, yes, mass was always conserved and was never destroyed. But that's not entirely correct. The meaning of the well known equation $E=mc^2$ is that energy and mass can be converted into each other, with the exchange rate being determined by this equation. So total mass is NOT conserved. The total energy is NOT conserved, either. But the total mass–energy (the sum of all the mass AND all the energy in a closed system) IS conserved.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens to a particle and antiparticle that collide?

The 511keV/c² electron is typically converted into a 511keV photon, and the 511keV/c² positron is converted into another 511keV photon. However it needn't be a 1:1 conversion. Check out [positronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium#States) where you can read that the triplet state's leading decay is to three gammas. That's three photons, not two.

> Matter can never be destroyed, so what happens to those particles?

Matter can be destroyed. After [electron-positron annihilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation#Electron.E2.80.93positron_annihilation) no matter remains. However the energy is not destroyed. *Energy* can never be destroyed, not matter. See Einstein's [E=mc² paper](http://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/E_mc2/www/) where Einstein wrote an L instead of an E, and you can read that *"if a body gives off the energy L in the form of radiation, its mass diminishes by L/c²*". Electron-positron annihilation is where each body gives off radiation such that its mass diminishes to zero, and then it isn't there any more.

> Do they just disappear?

No. They are converted into light.

> Where does the mass go?

Note Einstein's last line: *"If the theory corresponds to the facts, radiation conveys inertia between the emitting and absorbing bodies".* Light  conveys inertia, and light has a non-zero ["inertial mass"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=light+%22inertial+mass%22&hl=en-GB&biw=&bih=&gbv=2&oq=light+%22inertial+mass%22&gs_l=heirloom-serp.3...17641.19482.0.19872.2.2.0.0.0.0.78.141.2.2.0....0...1ac.1.34.heirloom-serp..1.1.63.11dkcDHi1VU). The rest mass is converted into inertial mass.

But mass is an ambiguous word. Nowadays when people say mass without qualification, we assume they mean rest mass. So inertial mass is arguably archaic, and the photon has no rest mass because it's never at rest. So to avoid confusion it's better to say mass is converted into energy.